# Problem with using "Optimistic locking" I can not update after viewing the table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm add tcn in table:

```
alter table accounts add TCN integer;
```

And `UPDATE accounts set TCN = DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;`

And tcn can not be null `alter table accounts modify TCN not null;`

I created trigger before update

```
SQL> create or replace trigger acc_preupdate
  2  before update on accounts
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5  if(:NEW.TCN != :OLD.TCN+1) THEN
  6  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Concurrency Failure');
  7  end if;
  8  :NEW.TCN := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  9  END;
 10  /
```

And trigger before insert

```
SQL> create or replace trigger acc_preinsert
  2  before insert on accounts
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5  :NEW.TCN := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;
  6  end;
  7  /
```

I insert in table

```
SQL> insert into accounts (acc_id, acc_name, acc_amount, acc_date)
  2  values(acc_seq.nextval, 'petar', 15000, sysdate);
```

And when I want to update the table, I get this error

```
SQL> update accounts
  2  set acc_amount = 1000000
  3  where acc_id = 1;
update accounts
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Concurrency Failure
ORA-06512: at "PETAR1.ACC_PREUPDATE", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PETAR1.ACC_PREUPDATE'
```

now I select users with id 1.

```
select acc_name, acc_amount from accounts where acc_id = 1;
```

And when I try to update the table again, I get the same error.

Why can not I update the table?

I use Oracle 12c r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final `update` statement you do not specify an update to `TCN`, so in the `update` trigger, the value of `:OLD.TCN` is what you had inserted before (via the `insert` trigger). Since the `update` does not explicitly change it, also `:NEW.TCN` is that same value.

So `:OLD.TCN` is equal to `:NEW.TCN` and making the `if` condition in the `update` trigger true, raising your custom exception.

Comment: Thank you very much, when I update tcn with one number higher, everything works well.

Comment: What do you think about my code is it okay to do that?

Comment: You seem to want to implement optimistic locking, but then your update statements must include a where clause with the expected value of TCN (which should be queried before). Then the update should increment TCN. If a concurrent update happens the TCN will not match with the one in the WHERE clause. However, this comment section is not suitable to discuss all that. Please read about how to implement it. For instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008087/5459839)