# How to use optimistic locking within procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I implemented an optimistic lock with a trigger, how can I do it without a trigger within procedure?

I reading this post [Implementic Optimistic Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006941/implementing-optimistic-locking-in-oracle/41008087#41008087)

But I do not understand how I will implement it in the procedure.

I tried this, but I don't get what I expected

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS
  2       PROCEDURE upd_account
  3          (p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
  4            , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
  5            , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
  6            , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type
  7          , p_acc_version accounts.acc_version%type
  8          )
  9           IS
 10         BEGIN
 11             UPDATE accounts
 12             set acc_name    = acc_name
 13           , acc_amount  = acc_amount
 14           , acc_date    = acc_date
 15           , acc_version = acc_version + 1
 16     where acc_id   = p_acc_id
 17     and  acc_version = p_acc_version;
 18  if(SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0)
 19  THEN
 20  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Oops, the row has changed since you read it.' );
 21  END IF;
 22   END;
 23   end account_api;
 24  /

SQL> begin
  2  account_api.upd_account(1, 'user12', 1200, sysdate, '11-NOV-18 06.10.01.660948 AM');
  3   end;
  4  /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I'm trying the code with the same timestamp and it's done now

```
   SQL> begin
      2  account_api.upd_account(1, 'user1', 1200, sysdate, '11-NOV-18 06.10.01.660948 AM');
      3   end;
      4  /
    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: *I don't get what I expected"*: it would be useful if you specify what you *do* get, and how that is different from what you expected.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: You are supposed to pass a number as last argument, not a date string.

Comment: Column version is a timestamp data type, how should i forward the number?

Comment: It should not be a timestamp data type, but a plain number. You'll have to alter the data type. The idea is that it functions as an incremental version number: 1, 2, 3 ... reflecting the number of updates that record has received.

Comment: Now is the data type number.
The number in the table increases but I never get a mistake, even when the number is wrong in insert statement

Comment: Have you verified that the record is really updated?

Comment: Also, you could print the value of `SQL%ROWCOUNT` by doing `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
('Number of updated records: ' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT));` and put that immediately before the `IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0)`

Comment: I checked the row is always updated even when I write any number, he only adds one to that number.

I added   `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number of updated records: ' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT));`

Comment: Are you sure you have `and  acc_version = p_acc_version;` in the `where` clause?

Comment: it was an error, sorry.

Thank you for your time to help me, this means a lot to me.
Could you tell me if my implementation method is good?

Comment: Well, it is not good as it is in the question (leave it like that please), but if now it works, and things are done like I put in my answer, it should be fine.

Comment: I do not know how to do it, I have less than 15 reputations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you would have first selected a record (through a `select` query) and then decide to update it. The procedure you quoted is correct. It requires that you pass it the value of `acc_version` as last argument. You have that value from the record you queried.

This is a kind of contract you have to follow: you need to query that `acc_version` and then pass it to the procedure for the update you want to make. After each update, you have to re-query what the current value of `acc_version` is if you still need to make more updates.

The `app_version` field needs to be a number (not a date). It is intended to reflect the version of the record, like version 1, 2, 3, ... which can be seen as the number of updates that have been done on that particular record.

The procedure will make the update *on the condition* that this value in the record was not updated in the mean time (by some other update). It uses a simple `where` clause for that check.

If the update does not update anything, then it means the record did not satisfy this condition any more (and was altered). In that case the exception is raised.

But if the `acc_version` is still as you passed it to the procedure, the `update` statement will indeed update the targeted record. At the same time the `update` statement increments `acc_version`. This will prevent other clients who had already queried this record *before* this update, to make updates. They will need to re-query the record to get the right value of `acc_version`, and try again.

Comment: The problem is because the result is always execute, I'm gonna set up the code now

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to achieve

```
   PROCEDURE upd_account
                    (   p_acc_id      accounts.acc_id%type
                      , p_acc_name    accounts.acc_name%type
                      , p_acc_amount  accounts.acc_amount%type
                      , p_acc_date    accounts.acc_date%type
                      , p_version     accounts.version%type
                    )
                     IS
                  BEGIN
                      UPDATE accounts
                      set acc_name    = p_acc_name
                    , acc_amount  = p_acc_amount
                    , acc_date    = p_acc_date
                    , version = p_version + 1
             where acc_id = p_acc_id
             and version = p_version;
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Number of updated records: ' || TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT));
          if(SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0)
          THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Oops, the row has changed since you read it.' );
          END IF;
           END;
```

Comment: Warning! Here you did not put the `id` check in the `where` clause. This is NOT correct. You need to make sure the update *only* happens to the intended record (with a certain ID value). The way you have it now you risk to update multiple records when by coincidence they share the same `version` value.

Comment: For the version I use DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME, but you're right, is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, it is OK now.