# Check for "lost update" with system attribute/column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there a system attribute/virtual column that changes if I update a row? Or do I need a custom timestamp attribute for such purpose? I would like to use such attribute to check for lost updates in a web application. I'am not within a database transaction. So "serializable isolation level" is no option here.

By the way: How checks Oracle for updates internally?

Example:

Table `foo`:

```
ID    ATTR1    SYS_ATTR
-----------------------
1     foo      X1

UPDATE foo
SET attr1 = 'bar'
WHERE id = 1;

ID    ATTR1    SYS_ATTR
-----------------------
1     bar      Z1 -- <- changed too
```

Oracle 11g

Comment: Oracle tracks transactions in the redo and archived redo logs. Transactions are transparent until the results are committed by the originating session. There are ways to implement things like change data capture, or you might be able to get creative with the use of materialized view logs, but otherwise there is no inherent metadata in the table to let you know when a row has been changed. It is common practice to add your own last_updated and last_updated_by columns to tables and populate them with triggers when tracking that information is important.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that out-of-the-box in 11g. Generally you would need to provide your own attributes for that kind of tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to have your own timestamp column to implement [optimistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006941/implementing-optimistic-locking-in-oracle) in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I found that there's a solution in contrast to the comments above. In case of optimistic locking one can use [ORA_ROWSCN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953) pseudocolumn in combination with the [ROWDEPENENCIES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#CJAEEGDA) table option.