# Transaction management related questions

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am a bit confused in solving this because basically in transactions we have commit, rollback, and savepoints but what I have to do with these below question

Start a required number of sessions and write code to illustrate the concept of
a. reader does not lock another reader
b. writer does not lock a reader
c. writer locks another writer

Answer (score 0):

Concepts like transaction, commit, savepoint and rollback all apply to a single session: A single user doing something in a single database session. Locking is what happens for *other* users on that same system when a user does something. Lots of information about that on the web and stack overflow. The answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006941/implementing-optimistic-locking-in-oracle) explains it quite nicely but I'm sure you'll find other sources that explain the concepts.

Comment: How would I illustrate those 3 points(a, b, c) in the original question through code? It's more of a like we have to test simply with select or update statement

Comment: Well... that is the question _you_ need to answer. I can't do it for you. Read the concepts, look for examples, test. If you get stuck, ask a specific question. I can't make the assignments for you (I don't want to either :) )